# How do I assign the return value from a method to another object property in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm converting some old code to object literal notation in Javascript, and I'm afraid I've hit a bit of a bugbear. I know how to define properties, and I know how to define methods, but what if I want to assign the return value from a method as a property?

I've supplied code with the error output from Chrome's console. I can't see what I'm doing wrong, but the console is telling me that I'm either trying to go to something nonexistent in the global scope, or just something nonexistent. Here it is:

Code:

```
var testobj = {
    a: 2,
    b: 4,
    c: function() {
        return this.a * this.b;
    },
    d: this.c(), // OK, got it, it's trying to call it from global scope. Fine.
    e: function() {
        if (this.d) {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
            console.log(this.d);
        } else {
            console.log("ERROR");
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'c'
```

New code:

```
var testobj = {
    a: 2,
    b: 4,
    c: function() {
        return this.a * this.b;
    },
    d: testobj.c(), // but if I change it like this, it still doesn't work. What gives?
    e: function() {
        if (this.d) {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
            console.log(this.d);
        } else {
            console.log("ERROR");
        }
    }
}
```

New error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'c' of undefined
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it by using:

```
var testobj = {
    a: 2,
    b: 4,
    c: function() {
        return this.a * this.b;
    },
    d: function() {
        return this.c();
    },
    e: function() {
        if (this.d) {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
            console.log(this.d);
        } else {
            console.log("ERROR");
        }
    }
}
```

When you do `d: this.c()`, `this` is actually the global object. This is because, at the time of creating your `testobj`, the scope is the global object, so `this` is the global object.

If you use

```
d: function() {
    return this.c();
}
```

you're just setting `testobj.c` to a certain function. The `this` inside that function is only evaluated when you call `d`. So when you do call `d`, it will check the scope and see that the scope is `testobj`. And as `testobj` has a `c` function, it wall call and return that.

I've put this in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XMsMt/1/) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

This works ((http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/n6YjE/):

```
var testobj = {
    a: 2,
    b: 4,
    c: function () {
        alert(this.a + this.b);
    },
    d: function () {
        this.c();
    }
};

testobj.c();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to see the return value of the c in d.

In this cases I assign d after the object as it doesn t have any instance in `var ob = {...}` as it is still being created.

```
var testobj = {
    a: 2,
    b: 4,
    c: function() {
        return this.a * this.b;
    },
    e: function() {
        if (this.d) {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
            console.log(this.d);
        } else {
            console.log("ERROR");
        }
    }
}

testobj.d = testobj.c();

alert(testobj.d);
alert(testobj.c());
```

Comment: In this case, if you change `a` or `b`, `c` will change, but `d` won't. This might be what you want, or not. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: yes I thought this is what OP asked otherwise  why he would define two exactly same property obj.c() == obj.d() will always return same. But in this case he can do if (obj.c() != obj.d ) alert("changed"); trigger change function.

Comment: aha, true, I hadn't looked at it like that.